Cloth doesn't collide on the character's surface
I want to use Blender's cloth simulation to add a jacket to my character, but when it collides, the jacket ends up moving inside the character's body.


I have checked that the normals of both the character and the jacket are facing outward.


I have also tried adjusting the distance setting in the object collision properties.



I’ve also made sure that the cloth modifier is below the armature modifier in the stack.

But, the issue still exists

"I’ve also made sure that the cloth modifier is below the armature modifier in the stack." <-- the jacket that you want to sew should only have a Cloth modifier, no Armature modifier. In addition, I would limit the Max Sewing Force. A value of 0 means no limit and this can pull the cloth mesh into the body because the force is too strong. Try 5, 12, 20 or 50 or even 80. The value depends on the number of vertices and the Cloth > Physical Properties > Vertex Mass, among other things. Try a small value and increase it if needed.
